# react-router v4 nesting routing issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have a following situation:

```
<Wrapper>
   <Container>
      <Route exact path="/" component={UserListing} />
      <Route path="/user/:id" component={UserDetails} />
      <Route exact path="(/|/user/\d+)" component={StaticComponent} />
   </Container>

   <Route path="/create-account" component={CreateAccount}/>
</Wrapper>
```

Okey, so my case is simple: I don't want the `Container` component to render if path does not equal to `"/"` or `"/user/:id"`.
So if path is `"/create-account"` only `Wrapper` with `CreateAccount` as child should appear, without `Container`.

Looking for some help. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom component that decides whether or not to render Container like

```
const RouterRenderer = ({ location, children }) => {
    if(location && location.state && location.state.noMatch) {
        return null;
    }
    return children;
}
```

And a sub component which tells this container that nothing matched like

```
const NoMatch = () => {
    return <Redirect to={{state: {noMatch: true}}} />
}
export default withRouter(NoMatch);
```

Now you can use them like

```
<Wrapper>
   <RouterRenderer>
       <Container>
          <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={UserListing} />
              <Route path="/user/:id" component={UserDetails} />
              <Route exact path="(/|/user/\d+)" component={StaticComponent} />
              <NoMatch />
          </Switch>
       </Container>
   </RouterRenderer>
   <Route path="/create-account" component={CreateAccount}/>
</Wrapper>
```

> **P.S.** Note that its important to use `Switch` when you are using `NoMatch` component since you want to render it only when no other
>   route matched. Also you can write RouteRenderer function in the form
>   of an HOC instead of a functional component.

Comment: Is it possible to fix my case only with `Route`? Without this all stuff with props handling and `Redirect`?

Comment: @Patrickkx, the above case handles your usecase in a general manner, also its possible to handle it without the above method, but that would require you to actually specify all possible routes as a regex while Container and rendering its as a Route