# If component returns null in its render function, why componentDidMount is triggered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been using React for a while, but today I started wondering about one thing.

Why `componentDidMount` method is fired even though my render function returns `null`?

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html):

> `componentDidMount()` is invoked immediately after a component is
>   mounted (inserted into the tree). Initialization that requires DOM
>   nodes should go here. If you need to load data from a remote endpoint,
>   this is a good place to instantiate the network request.

As I understand it correctly: component returns `null`, so that there's nothing to mount in the DOM tree and `componentDidMount` should not be fired.

Comment: Its not just about rendering, there are instances where you can use the React component lifecycle methods to take other action. You can find one such instance in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51600769/react-router-v4-nesting-routing-issue/51600907#51600907

Comment: I always though that "mounted (inserted into the tree)" means that the parent component did request an instance, regardless whether or not the component will render itself (with DOM nodes) or not (with `null`)

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`componentDidMount()` will fire exactly after `render()`! so you're saying that your render function returns `null`, which means render function executes!

### Proof:

If you put a `console.log` inside your render function, exactly before `return` (what I do most of time for checking stuff like state updation or checking if current component receives props from parent component) you will see that log result in the console, which means that javascript executes the render.

It doesn't matter what it will render, `null` or hundred lines of `jsx`

Comment: OK, but the documentation is not so clear about this - especially this sentence: "after a component is mounted (inserted into the tree)"

Comment: so the difference is that now you inserting `null` to the dom tree ... hahaha

Comment: but the point is that you **inserting** something to the DOM , in your case `null`

Comment: As per [my feedback here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51376758/472495) on your now deleted question: (1) you very rarely need line breaks `<br>` in your posts here - use double Enter to create a paragraph break; (2) when referring to yourself, "I" should be a capital letter; (3) Sentences start with a capital letter. Please try to avoid these mistakes for your future posts, to reduce the amount of volunteer repair work required.

Comment: If you think of Stack Overflow as being more like Wikipedia, and less like a chatroom, that may be a helpful way of understanding

Comment: I believe this "but the point is that you inserting something to the DOM , in your case null" is the answer in general

Comment: Right at this moment I'm fixing a bug in a huge corporate app that was caused by someone assuming that returning null won't trigger componentDidMount.